android startIntentSenderForResult deprecated
I have this code:
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == BackupActivity.REQUEST_AUTHORIZE) { ... etc

and when authorizing the user to Google Drive, showing the available accounts, I am using startIntentSenderForResult(pendingIntent.getIntentSender(), REQUEST_AUTHORIZE, null, 0, 0, 0, null); according to Google documentation.
However this is deprecated. Is there a way to replace it in my code context? Maybe with ActivityResultCallback or any other working solution?
Identity.getAuthorizationClient(this)
                .authorize(authorizationRequest)
                .addOnSuccessListener(
                        authorizationResult -> {
                            if (authorizationResult.hasResolution()) {
                                // access needs to be granted by the user
                                PendingIntent pendingIntent = authorizationResult.getPendingIntent();
                                try {
                                    assert pendingIntent != null;
                                    startIntentSenderForResult(pendingIntent.getIntentSender(), REQUEST_AUTHORIZE, null, 0, 0, 0, null);
                                } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {                                   
                                }
                            } else {
                                 try {
                                    handleSignInInent(authorizationResult);
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                                }
                            }
                        })
                .addOnFailureListener(e -> Log.i("TTTT", "Failed to authorize", e));

I tried this:
   private final ActivityResultLauncher<IntentSenderRequest> authorizationLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
        new ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult(),
        result -> {
            if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                // Authorization was successful
                // Handle the result, e.g., call handleSignInIntent
                try {
                    handleSignInInent(Identity.getAuthorizationClient(this).getAuthorizationResultFromIntent(result.getData()));
                } catch (IOException | ApiException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            } else {
                // Authorization failed or was canceled
                Log.i("TTTT", "Authorization failed or was canceled");
            }
        }
);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = authorizationResult.getPendingIntent();
                        try {
                            assert pendingIntent != null;
                            authorizationLauncher.launch(new Intent().setIntentSender(pendingIntent.getIntentSender()));
                        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                            Log.i("TTTT", "Couldn't start Authorization UI: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                        }

But in second part of my code Cannot resolve method 'setIntentSender' in 'Intent'

Your authorizationLauncher takes an IntentSenderRequest, it doesn't take anything you create by using new Intent(). Is there a reason you aren't using the IntentSenderRequest.Builder to construct one of those?

ah ok, I now used authorizationLauncher.launch(new IntentSenderRequest.Builder(pendingIntent.getIntentSender()).build()); and seems it is working. You can post it as an answer, Thank you!
